# Explain how the Radio button works for form_for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Please suggest its proper syntax
I want that user should be either male or female
I am not able to find out its proper use.

This is my form, on clicking the radio buttons both are selected and it stays selected.
I want that user should choose either male or female.

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>  
      <div class="well-lg">
      <h4>Personal Details</h4>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :First_Name %><br />
         <%= f.text_field :fname, :class=> 'form-control' %>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :Last_Name %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :lname, :class=> 'form-control' %>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :Email_Address %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :email, :class=> 'form-control' %>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :Mobile_No%><br />
        <%= f.text_field :mob, :class=> 'form-control' %>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :Gender %> <br />
        <%= f.label :Gender, 'male' %>
        <%= f.radio_button :gender_male, 'male' %>
        <%= f.label :Gender, 'female' %>
        <%= f.radio_button :gender_female, 'female' %><br />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :Country %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :country, :class=> 'form-control' %>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :State %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :state, :class=> 'form-control'  %>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :Suburb %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :suburb, :class=> 'form-control'  %>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :Postal_Code %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :postal, :class=> 'form-control'  %>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :Address %><br />
        <%= f.text_area :add, :class=> 'form-control' %>
      </div>
      <div class="button">
        <%= f.submit "Next" %>
      </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Pls help me on this

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :fname
      t.string :lname
      t.string :email
      t.string :mob
      t.string :gender
      t.string :country
      t.string :state
      t.string :suburb
      t.string :postal
      t.string :add
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this .......

```
<div class="form-group">
   <%= f.label :gender %> <br />
   <%= f.label :gender_male, 'male' %>
   <%= f.radio_button :gender, 'male', :checked => true %>
   <%= f.label :gender_female, 'female' %>
   <%= f.radio_button :gender, 'female' %><br />
</div>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: its not getting stored in the database

Comment: Please post your controller code that handles your database inserts.

Comment: Thank you akshay..got where i was wrong..i m upvoting your answer..pls upvote my question

Answer (score 0):

To be able to select a single radio from several, you need to group them.

To group them, assign the same name

```
<%= f.radio_button :gender_male, 'gender' %>
<%= f.radio_button :gender_female, 'gender' %>
```

Comment: can you pls help me with some syntax

Comment: I just updated my answer. See if it's clear enough :)

Comment: now i can select between the two but nothing is stored in the database @Alex

Comment: Please post the code that handles your database inserts. Also, a `gender` column should exist in your table.

Comment: i added migration table

Comment: Try changing `<%= f.radio_button :gender_male, 'male' %>` to `<%= f.radio_button :gender, 'male' %>` and the same for female

Comment: @VijayJadon, try radio_button_tag instead of radio_button if you dont want to store gender column in db.

Comment: Thank you for this *assign the same name*, I missed it, I was wondering how come I could select all at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

try this => radio_button_tag :gender, 'male'

radio_button_tag :gender, 'female'

Hope this will  help you.

Comment: its need to be saved in the database so i can't use radio_button_tag @chitra